# SQL data type that automatically sets to field length of value

Tags: sql, types, varchar

Does such a thing exist or are you always required to set the max field length manually?

We have a `varchar` field in our database where the length of the value can be anything from 0 all the way to 800 or greater. Is there a datatype that will automatically set itself to the length of the value being entered?

Comment: nope there is no such thing

Comment: This is why you can't declare a `VARCHAR` without specifiying its size.

Comment: you need to define the **maximum** length - but the `Varchar` type will always only store as much data as needed... if you have `varchar(800)` and store 50 characters - it takes up 52 bytes. If you store 100 characters - 102 bytes used (2 bytes overhead per entry)

Comment: marc_s: Do you want to add that as an answer?

Comment: The problem is that you set the max *before* data is in the table.  There are some datatypes which store as much as needed, like long var char and blob.

Comment: @marc_s depends on the database vendor's implementation, (and Neal did not specify).  Some, maybe most, will reserve 800 bytes for each record in the RID table for a varchar(800).  Also, buffers to hold the field will be 800 bytes and there may be 800 bytes reserved in the packet for the client server communication.

Comment: @MarlinPierce: OK - sorry - I only know SQL Server well enough to say that SQL Server **does not** just blindly reserve or transmit 800 bytes (unless you actually store 800 bytes in that column)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(*this is specifically for SQL Server - but should apply to most other RDBMS as well*)
You need to define the **maximum** length - but the `varchar` type will always only store as much data as needed. So need to define the max - but not the actual size - that's handled automatically.

So if you have `varchar(800)` and store 50 characters - it takes up 52 bytes. If you store 100 characters - 102 bytes used (2 bytes overhead per entry).

At the same time, I would still argue you should **NOT** just define all column `varchar(max)` (2 GB max. size) - even though it might look tempting and convenient. Read [What's the Point of Using VARCHAR(n) Anymore?](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/whats-the-point-of-using-varchar%28n%29-anymore/) for a great explanation of why not to do that.